# SharePoint CSOM Unit Testing

Tags: unit-testing, c#-4.0, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, csom

I am currently using CS-OM to upload/download files from SharePoint 2013 sites. I would like to know what would be the best way to unit test my operations. Is there a way I could create a fake SharePoint site within my test and then running my tests against this fake site.

For starters I would like to know how I could unit test this 
**var clientContext = new clientContext(url)**.I would first like to create a fake SharePoint site with this url and then test this above piece of code to check if the context was loaded or if there were any errors. The urls will be dynamic based on some conditions and I would like to test if for a particular condition the particular context generation was successful or not.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".